# How to show autocomplete search result as a link

Tags: jquery-ui, laravel-5, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have successfully implemented autocomplete search option in my laravel project "book shop managing". Again from my homepage if I click on the name of a book then it would show the specific book. But how can I add link to my search result, so that if I click on a book from the result then it would take me to the page that contains the book details.

my index.blade.php

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#books" ).autocomplete({
                source: 'auto_complete'
            });


        });

    </script>

    <div class="ui-widget">
        <label for="books">Books: </label>
        <input id="books">
    </div>
```

controller

```
public function search(){
        $search = Input::get('term');

        $books = Book::where('title','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();

        foreach ($books as $book) {
            $data[] = $book->title;
        }

//        return $books;
        return $data;
    }
```

route

```
Route::get('auto_complete', 'BooksController@search');
```

Comment: Can you provide some example of your `$books` data?

Comment: here I am fetching the title of the book only. like-> Harry Potter, Sleeping Beauty

Answer (score 0):

CONTROLLER

```
public function search(){
        $search = Input::get('term');
        // return $search or dd($search) check if request get the value please
        $books = Book::where('title','like','%'.$search.'%')->get();
        // return $books or dd($books) check if request get the values please
        $results = array();
        foreach($books as $key => $v){
        $results[]=['id' => $v->id];
    }
    // return a json object
    return response()->json([
              'suggestions'=>$results]);
    }
```

JS

```
$(function() {
        $( "#books" ).autocomplete({
            source: 'auto_complete',
            onSelect: function (data) {
                location.href = "www.yourwebsite.com+data.suggestions.id" // this redirect for example book id:1 to www.yourwebsite.com/1
            // Or use jquery to redirect: window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
}
        });


    });
```

Use the same route, let me know if there is some error in network or console!
I supposed that you integrated the jquery library and autocomplete library js :)

Comment: if I return like
 return response()->json([
              'suggestions'=>$results]);
    } 
then, when I search for an element nothing is shown in the output field.